# Laravel Herd - Can not use .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, nginx

I've a standard PHP project.
And it has htaccess file like below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage tr-TR
Options +FollowSymLinks

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?git=$1  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?git=$1&second=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?git=$1&second=$2&third=$3 [L,NC]
```

But when I run my project, .htaccess can not be worked.
How can I enable htaccess on laravel herd?

Comment: Nginx doesn't support .htaccess files. Only Apache does.

Comment: Yep. To add more details, Laravel Herd doesn't come with Apache support and .htaccess files are configuration files that can override, per folder, main configs made at the root module level. Nginx has made the decision, early in its first versions, that no such directory-level configuration files would exist because there's a huge overhead to scanning the folders on-disk to find those files at runtime (per-request). That's one of the many reasons that Nginx is considered to be more performant. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/